# How to have an element's background be as wide as the overall wrapper?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a tree that's built similarly to this one: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jayhilwig/hv8vU/)

However in my case each element, when selected or hovered, needs to have a background that's as wide as the `<div class="tree well">` element. Everything in the tree is positioned relatively because of the pseudo elements. The selectable elements themselves don't have pseudo elements attached, so I can use one with absolute positioning to be the background. The problem is that the background pseudo element needs to have its `top` and `height` css attributes relative to its immediate parent, but `left` and `width` should be relative to the tree wrapper and that wrapper has a flexible size that's not the same as the screen.

Comment: Where is your code? Something "similar" doesn't cut it.

Comment: @SergChernata The structure is the same. I'm using `<div>`s instead of `<ul>`s and `<li>`s. If it works for this tree it will work for my tree.

Comment: I think you should set up a new fiddle or native snippet and add your hypothetical pseudo element scenario so that we can look at something specific here.

Comment: Please post your work or progress, so we can help you with this. Right now, we don't know what you did and want.